# Get Cell Drop Box - not just values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script in Google sheets to pre-populate a cell with a drop box when a new row is added. Cell `A1` of the spreadsheet has a basic drop box selector (data validation) with a couple of choices in it. The drop box is not connected to anything and is not used for any actions. I just want to copy that drop box into the first cell of each new row that I add to the sheet.

So far, the script I have will get the selected value of the drop box in `A1` and insert that value into the first cell of the new row. What I want is the entire drop box with all the choices to be added to each new row - not just the value.  Here's my script so far

```js
function myFunction(e) {
 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(e.changeType === 'INSERT_ROW') {
 var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
 var range = sh.getRange(1,1); 
 var dropbox = range.getValue();
 sh.getRange(row, 1).setValue(dropbox);
  }
}
```

So the GetValue() is not what I need.  Is there a way to get the entire drop box from A1 and copy it to the first cell in each new row added?  It would also be fine to programmatically create a simple drop box in the first cell of each new row, but I haven't found a way to do that either.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean [data validation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) as a drop box? If so, insert something like this code that gets the `DataValidation` rather than the `value`:

```
 var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
 var range = sh.getRange(1,1); 
 var dropbox = range.getDataValidation();
 sh.getRange(row, 1).setDataValidation(dropbox);
```

To illustrate, in [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13KDxfPclXiayYWD9z67F6vsqbfw_l8MoIjtAEbo36-I/edit#gid=0) if you run the below `myFunction()` it will get the data validation (i.e. *drop box*) in cell `A1` and set it into cells `A2:A10`.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/

function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var pullValidation = ss.getRange("A1").getDataValidation();
  ss.getRange("A2:A10").setDataValidation(pullValidation);
}
```